# The image in the raw html is not rendered in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to render a raw html (email). This html has an image.

```
<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/email/play_hydra_logo_email.png" alt="Google Play" style="border:none">
```

<kbd>[Live demo, showing image](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/4ac0vdeg/6/)</kbd>

[image]

But when I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, the image is not rendered.

<kbd>[Live demo, not showing image](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6rue3a?file=index.js)</kbd>

[image]

```
  render() {
    const content = `
<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/email/play_hydra_logo_email.png" alt="Google Play" style="border:none">
    `;

    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
    );
  }
```

How can I render it correctly? Thanks

---

**UPDATE**: I found if I change the image source to **https**, it will work.

Unfortunately, I don't have the control of the raw html, it is from email. How can I render image with url **http**?

It shows the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/email/play_hydra_logo_email.png'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Interesting. Any errors in the network tab or console?

Comment: @Chris oh, I just added the error too.

Comment: It seems both your examples (including the plain ol' image one) aren't working. Are you sure that `http` version isn't dead? I can't open it in my browser at all... EDIT: Ignore me, my router has just freaked out and is not serving up http content at all...

Comment: Use a regex to update all `http` in the HTML that matches a URL before setting it.

Comment: @Chris both are over http, the one on jsfiddle can show correctly (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

Comment: @DeepakKamat thanks, but this case is a little special. Most time the images in the raw html (email) does not have a https version. Only has http version.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, my net was playing up. Have you tried outside of jsfiddle? I just tried in my own local app running on https and http, both worked fine with the dangerouslySetInnterHTML version

Comment: @Chris hmm, I got same test result. Seems something else causing the issue. Might be related with server?.. I need further test.

Comment: I'd say its the way JSFiddle and the like are setup - usually iframes within iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the conversation in the comments, this appears to be linked to JSFiddle and possibly its use of iframes combined with requesting `http` resources from a `https` page.

Comment: Thanks, for the demo which cannot show image, I guess it is related with stackblitz I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Following the gnudi's reference, the **[RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)** section 5.2 says:

> If the scheme component is defined, indicating that the reference
>   starts with a scheme name, then the reference is interpreted as an
>   absolute URI and we are done. Otherwise, the reference URI's scheme is
>   inherited from the base URI's scheme component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
 <div>
        <img src='//gstatic.com/android/market_images/email/play_hydra_logo_email.png'                alt="Google Play"
            style={{border: 'none'}}/>
          
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help too!